# Docker-Machine create Windows 10: Problemas Powershell

Tags: docker, powershell, windows-10

Estou tentando criar uma docker-machine no windows 10 com o seguinte comando:

docker-machine --debug create --driver hyperv default2

debug completo: https://pastebin.com/ccAeqYxL

Mas estou tomando o seguinte erro, exatamento desta forma, com os carecters deste jeito como podem ver:

> ```
> (default2) DBG | [executing ==>] : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive New-VM default2 -Path 'C:\Users\obata\.docker\machine\machines\default2' -SwitchName 'Op��o Padr�o' -MemoryStartupBytes 1024MB
> (default2) DBG | [stdout =====>] :
> (default2) DBG | [stderr =====>] : New-VM : O Hyper-V n�o p�de localizar um comutador virtual com o nome "Op??o Padr?o".
> (default2) DBG | No linha:1 caractere:1
> (default2) DBG | + New-VM default2 -Path 'C:\Users\obata\.docker\machine\machines\defaul ...
> (default2) DBG | + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> (default2) DBG |     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-VM], VirtualizationException
> (default2) DBG |     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVM
> (default2) DBG |
> (default2) DBG |
> Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1
> notifying bugsnag: [Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1]
> ```

Comment: Só para testar, se você usar o nome `teste` no lugar de `Opção Padrão`, funciona? Se funcionar ou der um outro erro completamente diferente deve ser problema de encoding/charset. Se der o mesmo erro, então deve ser alguma outra coisa.

Comment: Ele da a mesma resposta:

New-VM : O Hyper-V não pôde localizar um comutador virtual com o nome "Teste".

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi este problema setando enconding do powershell com ajuda aqui:

https://gist.github.com/xoner/4671514